# Boolean Expression minimization

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Can someone help confirm that I simplified correctly?

$F=(\neg ( A * \neg B) * (B * \neg C) * \neg B ) + D$

For my answer, I get:

$F = A*\neg B*C+D$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Your answer is not correct, it simplify to $D$, just notice that the first term: $$(\neg ( A * \neg B) * (B * \neg C) * \neg B )$$ is a contradiction, since $B$ and $\neg B$ can never hold at the same time.

**Answer:** (Use [Laws of Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra))

> \begin{align}&(\neg ( A * \neg B) * (B * \neg C) * \neg B ) + D\\=&(\neg ( A * \neg B) * (\neg C * B) * \neg B ) + D\tag*{Commutativity}\\=&(\neg ( A * \neg B) * \neg C * (B * \neg B) ) + D\tag*{Associativity}\\=&(\neg ( A * \neg B) * \neg C * (0) ) + D\tag*{Complementation}\\=&~0 + D\tag*{Annihilator}\\=&~D\tag*{Identity}\\\end{align}